# How to understand turbo machines?(compressors,fans,pumps,turbines,etc..)

Tags: turbofan, compressor

From what I understood, the energy transfer between the blades and the fluid(fluid to blade or blade to fluid) occurs due to the curvature of the blade.Its because of this curvature the stream of the fluid is redirected, the whirl component of velocity changes, by applying momentum equation(newtons second law) a force acts on the fluid and then by newtons third law we can see that the blade is pushed in the opposite direction.But sometimes during lecture my professor used to say the blades have aerofoil cross section.But he never explained how that is significant in a compressor.Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Axial compressor blades are wings.  The airfoil cross section maximizes the efficiency of the compressor blade at generating lift to generate torque in the case of a turbine blade, or generating lift to create downwash that forces the air into a smaller space in the case of a compressor blade, compared to a blade that was flat or had a simple curve.

Pretty much same as a wing or propeller blade.  I can make a plane fly with sheets of plywood for wings, but it's way more efficient to use airfoil shapes in redirecting the air to generate the force I want.

Comment: So just a curve or slope(to redirect the stream) is sufficient for energy transfer.The only puropse of aerofoil cross section is to improve efficiency.Is this right?

Comment: Please notify me if this is not the right forum to ask this question.

Comment: @Mohan, yes, you could use flat plates for compressor blades and it would work.  It just would not be very efficient.  Efficiency is extremely important in jet engines, that's why designers spend so much time to get the exact perfect shape.

Comment: @Daniel Kiracofe Thank you.Nice answer, that clears my doubt.

Comment: Note that the main job of the stator vanes is to redirect and control the downwash of the upstream row of compressor blades so that the flow hits the next row of blades at the optimum angle for that row of blades.  That is why they are variable on pretty much all modern axial compressors and are continuously adjusted by the fuel control system.